# Delete parse object with editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am using editActionsForRowAtIndexPath function, so when i swipe on a cell i would like to delete the object from Parse and the table. I have a query and i believe that i am using the "wherekey" incorrectly. Could anyone help me figure what i need to compare so i can delete the object. My code is below...

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Events")
query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: (PFObject).self)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects :     [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       if error == nil {

          for object in objects! {
          object.deleteInBackground()
          print("event deleted")
       }
    }
})
// Refresh tableview
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing the correct process. The problems could be any of these from my point of view.

- `self.tableView.reloadData()` should be executed after the line `object.deleteInBackground()` since this method call takes a couple sections to complete. Therefore by putting the `tableView.reloadData()` inside the loop or just outside the for loops bracket will ensure it gets executed after the `deleteInBackground()` is completed.
- `(PFObject).self` could be nil
- Perform an `if let object == [PFObject]?` before looping over the 'objects' to ensure the object you retrieved is not nil

**Edit**

I overlooked the fact that your trying to filter the query by objectId which will always return one object since objectId is unique. Therefore you should be using the method

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(theObjectId) {
  (objectName: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil && objectName != nil {
     //delete object here
  } else {
     print(error)
  }
}
```

This means you only need to create the query and have no need for the whereKey method.

Refer to the parse documentation for retrieving objects [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-retrieving-objects)

Comment: How would i do this with code? and i believe that its to do with my where key because its not comparing? have i don that right? x